# How to use values such as 2014-03-31T15:00:33.000Z in QGIS Time Manager?

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I´m trying to use the QGIS Time Manager plugin but I have a problem with my attribute columns.

Time Manager supports %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S format but my dataset uses the following format in the timestamp column

```
2014-03-31T15:00:33.000Z
```

How can I use the plugin? 
Do I have to format my column ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two options:

1. change the values to one of the supported formats

   `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss
   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
   YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
   YYYY-MM-DD
   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS.ssssss
   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS
   YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM
   YYYY/MM/DD`
2. change the plugin source code to add your format. The relevant file is https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/blob/master/timevectorlayer.py

Comment: Thanks.I understood that I have to edit the plugin and run again with the shape. I´ll do.

Comment: Well. I chequed the plugin and find timevectorlayer.py and another file compilled. Which one I have to edit ?

Comment: The .py. Tho compiled one can be deleted or should be overwritten automatically anyway.

Answer (score 1):

A format string like `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ` should work for your layer. You can change the time format string for that layer in its entry in the Time Manager settings layer list.

[image]

The Time Manager plugin should then show something like this:

[image: Time manager]

For more information on the format codes, see the python [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) documentation.